# There's any way to change OCR font? Or at least select a specific one?

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract, easyocr

Recently I discovered that you could change EasyOCR/PyTesseract language selection, but my doubt goes beyond that. I need to use FE-Font, which is used in Car Plates and stuff, but the font design is different than usual, because of those differences the OCR goes crazy.

```
from easyocr import Reader
# this is just an example of what I mean by "changing language"

reader = Reader(['en'])
# Reader([font_path]) ? 

reader.readtext(fake_image_file)
```

Comment: Googling brought up this question, does this resolve the error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295527/tesseract-training-for-a-new-font